# sitfinity MVC wideget not accepting html tag through kendo text editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I am using MVC widget in sitefinity and trying to use a text editor so content manager are able to add HTML editor usng kendo, so they can make text bold and add bullit point, whenver i try saving the data i get error message below any ideas on how this can be fixed.

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (paragraph_text="asdsadasc fasdf

Controller:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateParagraph(contentModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

Model:

```
 [AllowHtml] 
 public string paragraph_text { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The then designer Js encode the string then decide before its rendered in the view. You will encode this in the apply changes function.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question but I came across this problem recently. To fix it we had to create a custom request validator class as outlined in this article: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-error

```
public class CustomRequestValidatorCustom : CustomRequestValidator
{
    internal static readonly string[] _nonValidatedFilePaths =
    {
        "/<controller>/<action>/",
    };

    protected override bool IsValidRequestString(HttpContext context, string value, System.Web.Util.RequestValidationSource requestValidationSource, string collectionKey, out int validationFailureIndex)
    {
        var isValid = base.IsValidRequestString(context, value, requestValidationSource, collectionKey, out validationFailureIndex);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            isValid |= context.Request.FilePath != null && context.Request.FilePath.In(_nonValidatedFilePaths);
        }

        return isValid;
    }        
}
```

Comment: It's irritating that SF doesn't recognize the [ValidateInput(false)] / [AllowHtml] data annotations.